# (Kivy/Python) Store text from textinput widget when user hits enter

Tags: python, kivy

I've been playing around with the kivy library and have been trying to create a GUI for the game hangman [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game))]. I'm trying to create a TextField that a user enters a single letter and it changes the button text **ONLY** when they press return/enter, instead of the constant stream that textinput.text gives .

I've looked at the docs and other stackoverflow Q&A's and it seems the solution lies with either the on_text_validate event or changing my Clock.schedule.interval setup, but I can't figure out how to implement it in my code.

My python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class HangmanBoard(BoxLayout):
    word = 'hangman'
    empty = ["_"]*len(word)

    def update(self, *args):
        empty_word = self.ids['labelA']
        letter_input = self.ids['labelB']

        guess = letter_input.text
        empty_word.text = ' '.join(self.empty)

        if guess in self.word:
            for i in range(len(self.word)):
                if guess == self.word[i]:
                    self.empty[i] = guess


        print(guess)

class HangmanApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = HangmanBoard()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HangmanApp().run() here
```

My Kv file:

```
<HangmanBoard>:
orientation: 'vertical'

Button:
    id: labelA
    font_size: 60
    size_hint: 1, 0.5
TextInput:
    id: labelB
    font_size: 60
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
    size_hint: 1, 0.5
    focus: True
    multiline: False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can either have a "when user stopped typing for 1 second" mechanic with Clock events or just have an `on_text_validate` update the button's text, the latter being simpler and more straight-forward:

```
TextInput:
    on_text_validate:
        labelA.text = self.text
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: No problem! Consider accepting the answer. I also have a project with the "when user stops typing" mechanic, so I can pull up the relevant parts if you will need it.